# .htaccess RewriteRule for one IP only (with regex subfolder)

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to rewrite requests such as:

- /98fj3JHgf-83j/

which would show that folder's index.html, to:

- /98fj3JHgf-83j/rewritten.html

but ONLY for a certain IP address. I'd rather put the .htaccess for this in the site root and forget about it, as the subfolder can be anything (not quite anything - a random string of uppercase and lowercase letters, numbers and dashes).

What I've got just now works, but I have to place the .htaccess in each subfolder: -

```
RewriteEngine On

# requests from 12.34.56.78 get rewritten.html instead of index.html
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^12\.34\.56\.78$
RewriteRule ^index.html$ rewritten.html
```

which is not ideal. A single .htaccess in the root would be great, so I'm guessing a little regex in the above somewhere?

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine On

# requests from 12.34.56.78 get rewritten.html instead of index.html
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^12\.34\.56\.78$
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-/]*)?index.html$ /$1rewritten.html
```

Comment: Thanks, but that gives a 404: -

The requested URL /rewritten.html was not found on this server.

Looks like it's looking in the root for the rewritten.html file?